# Expected behaviour of a stack implemented using Priority Queue using minHeap

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, priority-queue, min-heap

I am new to the concept of heaps and PQs. So I was trying to implement a Stack using PQ using a min heap. 
I am trying to implement following methods:

1. pop
2. pop
3. isEmpty
4. top
5. size

Below is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.System;
public class StackUsingMinPriorityQueue{
    static int a[] = {3,7,2,11,9,4};
    int size = 0;
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq;
    static StackUsingMinPriorityQueue obj;
    public static void main(String args[]){

        obj = new StackUsingMinPriorityQueue(a.length);
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            obj.push(a[i]);
        }


        System.out.println("Value popped: "+obj.pop());
        System.out.println("Value at Top: "+obj.top());
        System.out.println("PQ size: "+obj.size());
        System.out.println("PQ IsEmpty: "+obj.isEmpty());

    }
    public StackUsingMinPriorityQueue(int size){
        this.size = size;
        pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    }

    /**
     * 1. PUSH
     * **/
    public void push(int data){
         obj.insert(-System.currentTimeMillis(),data); 
    }

     public void insert(long time, int data) {
            pq.offer(data);
    }


    /**
     * 2. POP
     */ 
    public int pop(){
       return obj.extractMin();
    }

    public int extractMin() {
        return pq.poll();
    }

    /**
     * 3.TOP
     */
     public int top(){
         return pq.peek();
     }

    /**
     * 4. SIZE
     */
     public int size(){
         return pq.size();
     }

     /**
      * 5.IsEmpty
      */ 
     public boolean isEmpty(){
         return pq.isEmpty(); 
     }
}

Output: 
Value popped: 2
Value at Top: 3
PQ size: 5
PQ IsEmpty: false
```

Now, my query is the *value at top =3* . Is this correct ? Shouldn't it be the last value entered i.e 4?  My understanding is that as we are implementing a stack, a peek shall give the element at the top of the stack which shall be 4 and not 3.

Can someone please let me know if my implementation is incorrect or is my understanding?

Comment: Maybe this help you : 'pop()' Removes the object at the top of this stack and returns that object as the value of this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pq.poll()` and `pq.peek()` operates on the minimal element in the `pq`, while `pop` and `top` should return last inserted element.

To implement a stack using priority queue, you should add a key `-<insertion time>` to each value. You may use plain increasing counter as a "timer". Notice, that this implementations will be very inefficient.

Comment: Thank you. 
Can you please help me how can I declare my PQ in this case ? 
Like for building max heap, I used 
 pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(10, new Comparator<Integer>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
    return o2 - o1;
   }
  });

Comment: @nerd.postclass Entry {}

Comment: You should define `class Entry{int timestamp; int value}` and compare them using `timestamp`s.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, inefficient is the right word. Thank you.